# Error in the use of linked-lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

The function doesnt work. The rest of the code is okay. It finds the maximum in the lists (its also the last element of the list) and then doesn't quit the iteration, instead of that, the program crashes. I got a hint, that suggests, that I have problems wit the us of "()". Maxhelye means the max_pos

```
typedef short int shorti;



typedef struct szelveny{
        int szsorszam;
        int lsorszam;
        int het;
        shorti talalat;
        int tnyeremeny;
  }szelveny; //szelveny-->ticket, szsorszam-->ticketnumer, //lsorszam-->lotterynumber,het-->week, tnyeremeny-->prize



typedef struct szelveny_element{
       szelveny szelveny;
       struct szelveny_element *next;
   }szelveny_element,*szelveny_pointer;


typedef struct lottozo{

        int lsorszam; 
        shorti het;
        int sszelveny;
        int nyeremeny;
     } lottozo; //lottozo-->lottery


typedef struct lottozo_element{
      lottozo lottozo;
      struct lottozo_element *next;
   } lottozo_element,*lottozo_pointer; 


typedef struct het{
        shorti het;
        lottozo_pointer lhead;
        szelveny_pointer szhead;
     } het;


typedef struct het_element{
        het het;
        struct het_element *next;
     }het_element,*het_pointer;


szelveny_pointer    szelvenyek=0;
lottozo_pointer     lottozok=0;
het_pointer         hetek=0;


int maxnyeremenyhelye2(int ahet)     //maxprizeposition, ahet-->week got as parameter 
{
    int max=0,maxhelye=-1;
    het_pointer hp;
    for(hp=hetek;hp!=0;hp=hp->next)
        if(hp->het.het==ahet)
        {
            lottozo_pointer lp;
            for(lp=hp->het.lhead;lp!=0;lp=lp->next)
            {
                if(lp->lottozo.nyeremeny>=max)
                {
                    max=lp->lottozo.nyeremeny;
                    maxhelye=lp->lottozo.lsorszam;
                }

            }
        return maxhelye;    
        }
}
```

Comment: can you please show us the related structure definitions also?

Comment: Thank you so much. one more thing, while posting the code, please keep in mind, we're humans, not compilers. readibility matters, really. No offence. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your function `int maxnyeremenyhelye2(int ahet)` does not always return a value - didn't your compiler warn you about this? The line

```
return maxhelye;
```

should be moved down below the following brace.